# Find the real eigeensolution for this diffusive transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$u_t=(x^2u_x)_x$$
so far i got this

we know that 
$(x^2u_x)_x = 2xu_x + u_{xx}$, so now i have $u_t=2xu_x + u_{xx}$
$$T'X=X''T+2xX'T$$ using separable variable method i have 
$$\frac{T'}{T} = \frac{X''}{X} +\frac{2xX'}{X}$$ so the only way these two can be equal if they are both constant so $$\frac{T'}{T} = \frac{X''}{X} +\frac{2xX'}{X} = \lambda$$, that means $\frac{T'}{T} =\lambda$ and $\frac{X''}{X} +\frac{2xX'}{X} = \lambda$ , now we solve each separately $$\frac{T'}{T} =\lambda$$ $$T'=T\lambda$$ $$T'-T\lambda=0$$, let $\lambda = \omega ^2$ so possible eigeenfunctions are $e^{\omega t}$ and $e^{-\omega t}$.  we now solve the second equation. $$\frac{X''}{X} +\frac{2xX'}{X} = \lambda$$ $$X'' +2xX -\lambda X=0$$ this is an homogenous equation. now i need method of ODE to solve this. it  has been a long time so i do not remember to go about it. any help that would be appreciate it thanks

Comment: The solutions of your ODE is known as [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).

Answer (score 0):

Since that is an equation with non-constant coefficients but is not "equi-potential" (each coefficient a power of x equal to the order of the derivative) I would be inclined to use a power series method.  Let $X= \sum_{ni= 0}^\infty a_nx^n$.  Then $X'= \sum_{n= 1}^\infty n a_nx^{n-1}$ and $X''= \sum_{n= 2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$.  $xX'= \sum_{i= 1}^\infty na_n x^n$.  We can shift the index in the X'' sum by letting m= n- 2 so that n= m+ 2.  Then $\sum_{n= 2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}= \sum_{m= 0}^\infty (m+2)(m+1)a_{m+2}x^m$.